# What is the reason why I get a prerender error with the generate command when using the i18n package in Nuxt3?

Tags: i18next, nuxt3

When I use the Nuxt3 npm run generate command with the i18n package, I receive the following errors, but when I do not use the package, I do not receive the errors. How can I solve this error?

package.json: "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.4",

`modules: [
"@nuxtjs/i18n",
],

i18n: {
lazy: true,
langDir: "locales",
strategy: "prefix_and_default",
locales: [
{
code: "en",
iso: "en-US",
name: "English",
file: "en.json"
},
{
code: "tr",
iso: "tr-TR",
name: "Türkçe",
file: "tr.json"
},
],
defaultLocale: "tr",
}`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I searched for ways to run the npm run generate command with the i18n package but couldn't find it. Without this package, npm run generate command works.